# How to parse csv file into table view in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, csv

I want to parse a csv file into a table view in Iphone.

I have a csv file with latitude and longtitude and date in the following format.

```
-37.6704090666667;144.852821866667;2010-07-12 09:34:18
-37.6784624166667;144.867258566667;2010-07-12 09:35:18
-37.6886946666667;144.880478666667;2010-07-12 09:36:18
-37.71000224;144.89458948;2010-07-12 09:37:22
```

I would like to put the above data in a table where the latitude and the longtitude is in bold separated by a comma and the date below it in smaller lighter font. On clicking this i am taking it into the map with the pointer. I know how to do this but i would like to know how to put the data in the csv file in a table view. And also once i put this data into a table view, i would like to know how to check for invalid coordinates in the entire csv file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wonderful library for CSV Parsing

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Try it. It is simple

For the coordiane validation, you can simply include a checking.
The latitude ranges in between -90 to +90. Longitude lies between -180 to +180. Include a simple validation for this

Answer (score -1):

Try this way...

```
path1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:CSVPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    path1=[path1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];
   NsArray* messArr=[path1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

//MessArr gives the all row from CSV FIle 


            for(i=1;i<[messArr count]-1;i++)
            {
                d=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                StrValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[messArr objectAtIndex:i]];
                StrValue=[StrValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
                StrValue=[StrValue stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                //  Here give whatever saperator you need to saperate data
                arr=[StrValue componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
          // This arr gives you the all threee data mean lat,long, & date
```

}

Comment: Please try to conform to the [naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW1)